# Splitting a line up into 2 different strings

Tags: python, file, coordinates, text-manipulation

So I have a file where a bunch of coordinates are in. But one x has its y value in the same line just seperated by a space. How do I split each line into two seperated pieces up so that I get the y and the x coord seperate(eg in a strig array)?
Coordinate example:

```
934 100
```

Comment: Simply use `line.split()`. It also works on lines with more than two coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simply use** `line.split()` for each string `line`.

It also works on lines with more than two coordinates.

Examples:

- `line = "934 100"`,
  `x, y  = line.split()`, `print(x,y) = 934 100`
- `line = "1 61  298   3333 "`, `a, b, c, d = line.split()`, `print(a,b,c,d) = 1 61 298 3333`

Answer (score 0):

Use split method to split the line default delimeter is space

```
with open("file") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line=line.strip().split()
        x=line[0]
        y=line[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Write as you say it - `split` the line on whitespace:

```
line = "934 100"
x, y = line.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename, "r") as fd:
lines_list = fd.readlines()
for index in range(len(lines_list)):
    x, y = lines_list[index].split(' ')
    print(x, y)
```

open file in read mode i.e "r"

```
with open(filename, "r") as fd:
```

Using readlines() we will get all the data of file in form of list of lines

```
lines_list = fd.readlines()
```

For each line split the line using space as delimiter and assign to x and y variables

```
x, y = lines_list[index].split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use split()**
List compression way of doing this is:

```
//suppose your input is 10 22
c=[int(temp) for i in input().split()]

//it will give us a list with elements [10, 22]
print(c) //[10, 22]
```

If you are reading from the file:

```
with open(file_path , "r") as file:
 lines_list = file.readlines()
 for index in range(len(lines_list)):
 x, y = lines_list[index].split(' ')
 print(x, y)
```

If you have it as a string:

```
s = “10 22”
x, y=s.split()
print(x, y) //10 22
```